# Does there exist such a unique triangle -2

Tags: coordinate-systems

In triangle $ABC$, the equation of median through $B$ and that of median through $C$ are respectively $x+y-2=0$ and $2x+y-3=0$. If the vertex $A$ is $(-2, 1)$, then does there exist such a unique triangle?

I think that the answer is positive. I assumed coordinates of $B$ and $C$ as $(b, 2-b)$ and $(c, 3-2c)$. Since the centroid is $(1, 1)$, thus I can get two linear equations in $b$ and $c$. This gives unique coordinates of $B$ and $C$. Is this the correct approach or is there another method?

Comment: Well, your assumption of coordinates of $B$ and $C$ as $(b, 2-b)$ and $(c, 3-2c)$ is correct. Your coordinates of the centroid are also correct. But how are you going to proceed? Why don't you find the midpoints of $AB$ and $AC$, and plug them in to the equations of the two medians to get the linear equations in $b$ and $c$? This can be done because the medians starting from vertices pass through the midpoints of respective opposite sides.

Answer (score 1):

Your method works fine. You get $b+c=5,b+2c=3$, so $b=7,c=-3$, so $B$ is $(7,-5)$ and $C$ is $(-2,7)$.

[image]

Of course, it is not **the** correct approach. There are usually many correct solutions!